# Same state in two different activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth-lowenergy, activity-state

I'm currently developing an Android application with BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) API basead on app distributed by Google Developers.

At this moment i already find devices, connect and receive notifications by slave (CC2540 TI).

My general propose is: I have an activity "A" that connects and shows at every 1second the received notifications (data string) and I want to move to activity "B" and continue receiving and visualizing at every 1 second the same data of activity "A", in other words, I want visualize and receive data in real time in more than one activity.

What is the best way/solution for this problem ? I have read  about put "extend Application" in my activity B so that access the whole state of activity "A" but i can't.

With intent I only pass to activity "B" one string and not various strings at 1second...

Can you help me ? I appreciate the attention.

Thanks a lot. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that manages the BLE connection that belongs to a class that extends Application. Create a get() method in the Application class so you can retrieve the class that manages the BLE connection in any Activity. 
I have an example project that does this with a Service (that I run a BLE connection within), but it is the same concept. It is intended to allow you to share BLE connections between Activities.

[Project Example](https://github.com/KEOpenSource/SharedService)

Comment: Thanks Kaleb for your quick response :) . I will see your example and try adapt in mine. Regards